# v-model is not updated in when using radio button in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-resource

I went through the documentation and I tried the following code. I can get the data for `enquiryDesc` but I'm always getting value 5 for rating. I also tried changing the radio group to a checkbox but it did not work.

My `html` form:

```
<form id="enquiryBox" method="POST" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit()">
  <div class="modal-body brbottom-20">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
      <fieldset class="rating">
                <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" value="5" ><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome">5</label>
                <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" value="4" ><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good">4</label>
    </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Enquiry</label>
          <textarea placeholder="Write your enquiry here" rows="7" id="enquiryDesc" name="enquiryDesc" class="form-control required" title="Desc" v-model="enquiryDesc" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <button id="btn-submit-enquiry" class="btn whiteButton" type="submit">Post Enquiry</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My Vue.js script:

```
enquiryBox = new Vue({
   el: "#enquiryBox",
   data: {
     rating: '',
     enquiryDesc: '',
   },
   methods: {
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
       var vm = this;
       data = {};
       data['rating'] = this.rating;
       data['enquiryDesc'] = this.enquiryDesc;
       console.log(data);

       $.ajax({
         url: 'https://api/post/add_review/',
         data: data,
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(e) {
           if (e.status) {
             alert("Success")

           } else {
             vm.response = e;

             alert(" Failed")
           }
         }
       });
       return false;
     }
   },
 });
```

My response for `console.log(data)`

`{rating: "", enquiryDesc: "hello how are you"}`

The value of rating never changes, it always stays 5.

Answer (score 1):

You should not bind the value to radio as you don't need to modify them so,

> **v-bind:value="5" and v-bind:value="4"** just remove this lines instead use normal **value="4" and value="5"**
>
> and in data you don't need to set **rating : 5**  just use **rating :''**
>   as user will select and then this data will be filled.

checkout this snippet.

```js
enquiryBox = new Vue({
   el: "#enquiryBox",
   data: {
     rating: '',
     enquiryDesc: '',
   },
   methods: {
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
       var vm = this;
       data = {};
       data['rating'] = this.rating;
       data['enquiryDesc'] = this.enquiryDesc;
       console.log(data);

       
       return false;
     }
   },
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>VueJS</title>
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
        <form id="enquiryBox" method="POST" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit()">
  <div class="modal-body brbottom-20">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
      <fieldset class="rating">
                <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" value="5" ><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome">5</label>
                <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" value="4" ><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good">4</label>
    </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Enquiry</label>
          <textarea placeholder="Write your enquiry here" rows="7" id="enquiryDesc" name="enquiryDesc" class="form-control required" title="Desc" v-model="enquiryDesc" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <button id="btn-submit-enquiry" class="btn whiteButton" type="submit">Post Enquiry</button>
  </div>
</form>    


</body>

</html>
```

other way click on number then press submit you can see its updated:

```js
var enquiryBox = new Vue({
   el: "#enquiryBox",
   data: {
     rating: '',
     enquiryDesc: '',
   },
   methods: {
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
       var vm = this;
       data = {};
       data['rating'] = this.rating;
       data['enquiryDesc'] = this.enquiryDesc;
       console.log(data);       
       return false;
     }
   },
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>VueJS</title>
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="enquiryBox">
        <form method="POST" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit()">
          <div class="modal-body brbottom-20">
            <div class="clearfix">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="form-group required">
                  <fieldset class="rating">
                    <span @click="rating = 1">1</span>
                    <span @click="rating = 2">2</span>
                    <span @click="rating = 3">3</span>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <button id="btn-submit-enquiry" class="btn whiteButton" type="submit">Post Enquiry</button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sir, I tried all those things. But nothing happens for me.. I am stuck on this for 2 days and still no luck

Comment: check out in snippet its working fine. if still its not working provide me working url or something like so i can debug it.

Comment: i am doing it in my locally and backend is django

Comment: not it will work on that case as well did you check snippet "Run Code snippet" and test it, in my answer , there its working

Comment: is there any other way.

Comment: ok can you share your modified code again so i can check it, other way will be there(instead of radio put some span and add data-rating="1" then write click event on them when user click get element then use event.target get that element and then find data-rating and manually set this.rating = data-rating) but this is proper way

Comment: added another way , you also need to set some css for that to look pretty :)

Comment: I am not sure its not Vue issue as i have also updated your code in my first snippet and it started working (may be there is some other code is also included and its creating issue ?), yes just 1, 2, 3 if you need extra feed back add method for click set active class for clicked element and so.. on

Comment: ohkiee .. i will try

Comment: <span>value: {{rating}}</span> BUT IT WILL REMAIN CONSTANT

Comment: when I use <select> Value is changing

Comment: When I use <select> I am able to change values <select class="dropdown" v-model="rating"> <option v-bind:value="0">Your rating</option> <option v-bind:value="1">1.Poor</option> </select> WHAT IS THE PROBLEM WITH <RADIO BUTTON>

Comment: I will suggest you to make your page at https://jsbin.com/ with your code and lets correct it there.

Comment: Sir.. this script icheck.min.js is causing me the problem. If I remove this script.. all the style does not work.. but radio buttons will work

Comment: may be its because in that script they may have used, event.preventDefault() so it won't get to your handler execute.

Comment: @Wanderer Having looked into that icheck.min.js script, it seems that it may be replacing the rendered checkboxes--specifically, it appears to take a checkbox and replace it with one wrapped in a div. Because of this behavior, the checkboxes are essentially becoming "unmounted" from the vue instance and will not trigger the updates you're expecting. To resolve this issue, either don't use that script, or use a combination of vue and jQuery (i.e. on submit, use jQuery for grabbing the checkbox value).

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue! I resolved it using :value and the @change event.

```
 <input :value="rating" @change="rating=$event" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" value="5">
```